# How to connect an address to the coinbase?

Tags: web3js, coinbase

Basicly I'm doing the beginners tutorial and it should show this

[image: With coinbase adress]

But For me it just does this

[image: Without adresses]

How can I make web3.eth.coinbase refer to my adress? Do I have to run a node or test-net?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
///First web3.eth.watch code to monitor coinbase


  web3.eth.watch('chain').changed(function(){
  var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
  document.getElementById('coinbase').innerText = coinbase;
  var balance = web3.eth.balanceAt(coinbase);
  document.getElementById('balance').innerText = web3.toDecimal(balance);
});



///Insert your contract address var here:


///Second web3.eth.watch code to monitor block number


</script>
```

Comment: Tell us a bit more about your setup and the exact tutorial that you're following. If you're working with the go-to Ethereum client (geth) then you can start the JavaScript console and set it via `web3.eth.coinbase=web3.eth.accounts[0]` (or whatever account you choose).

Comment: I was doing this tutorial https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/javascript-api-1/ and I just typed it into the sublimeText editor.

Comment: I added the code that I used

Comment: That is an incredibly out-of-date tutorial, unfortunately. Even if you were to connect a node, that version of web3 is long deprecated. [Here](https://ethereum.org/greeter) is a more modern tutorial, from the official Ethereum Foundation website.

Answer (score 1):

In Geth CLI, you can set your coinbase as follows:

```
miner.setEtherbase("0x123...");
```

**Edit:**
For web3, it is `web3.miner.setEtherbase("0x123...");`

Answer (score 1):

what do you get when you go into the JS Console of your local geth node and type in the following?

```
eth.coinbase
```

and what do you get when you put in

```
eth.accounts[0]
```

This way you could check if your node has a properly configured coinbase. The second command should output your default or primary account.
Using:

```
personal.listAccounts
```

will output all available accounts.

Personally I use:

```
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
```

to define my coinbase both in the JS Node as well as in web3.

I assume that within your HTML you point to web3.js?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new at this myself, but.....this gives you some practical guide lines into commands to get you started. have you run "geth account new"? that will attach a coinbase account to your mining operation.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: gottcha....new to forums in general and this one specifically....but huge amounts of good info here.